# using window.addSubview to add a UIView inside a tableView - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiwindow

I need to add a UITabBar to a TableView.
I add the following code in ViewDidLoad:

```
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        let tabBarCnt = UITabBarController()
        tabBarCnt.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.black

        let firstVc = UIViewController()
        firstVc.title = "First"
        firstVc.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: "Home", image: UIImage(named: "iconMenu"), tag: 0)
        let secondVc = UIViewController()
        secondVc.title = "Second"
        secondVc.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: "Location", image: UIImage(named: "iconMenu"), tag: 1)

        tabBarCnt.viewControllers = [firstVc, secondVc]

        window.addSubview(tabBarCnt.view)

    }
```

TabBar is properly appearing at the bottom on TableView, but the screen is stuck and none of the rows/bottomitems is clickable.

any advise?

Comment: None of this makes any sense. Why would you be creating a whole new tab bar controller with two view controllers in the `viewDidLoad` of some other view controller and then adding this tab bar controller as a subview of the window? What isn't that you really wish to accomplish?

Comment: I am not using a storyBoard, I just want the tabBar to be appearing on One Tableview and not on both. So when I clicked on the row on the First TableView, I will segue to another tableView with a TabBar. If instead of Window.addSubview I used self.view.addSubview, the application ran normally but the Tabbar is not appearing in the proper place. I just can see it if I scroll the view up

Comment: 1. present the tab controller, don't add it as a subview. 2. Don't do any of this in `viewDidLoad`. If you want it to appear when a row it selected, do it in the `didSelectRowAt` method. 3. Why are you adding 2 plain old `UIViewController`?

Comment: I will try one by one the above, but I have one small question, lets say if I proceed with the way I am proceeding, is there a way to remove the tabBarCnt after dismissing from the second TableView?